# Java equivalent to python all and any

Tags: java, python

How do I code in Java the following python lines?

```
a = [True, False]
any (a)
all (a)
```

---

inb4 "What have you tried?"

The sledge-hammer way would be writing my own `all` and `any` methods (and obviously a [class to host them](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html)):

```
public boolean any (boolean [] items)
{
    for (boolean item: items)
        if (item) return true;
    return false;
}

//other way round for all
```

But I don't plan on re-inventing the wheel and there must be a neat way to do this...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`any()` is the same thing as [`Collection#contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29), which *is* part of the standard library, and is in fact an instance method of all `Collection` implementations.

There is no built-in `all()`, however. The closest you'll get, aside from your "sledgehammer" approach, is [Google Guava's](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [`Iterables#all()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#all-java.lang.Iterable-com.google.common.base.Predicate-).

Comment: Thank you. So no avail in the stdlibs?

Comment: My heart fills with sadness and my eyes fill with tears. Thank you. Waiting on CD for accept.

Comment: Guava will make Java much nicer for you overall (and moreso when you can just lambdas, as in Java 8). Get acquainted.

Comment: Even if there is no bulit-in `all()`, you can easily get it using De Morgan's laws.  That is, `all(a) = !any(!a)`.

Comment: `any()` is **not** the same thing as `Collection#contains()`. `any()` can be given any iterable and it'll return `True` as soon as it encounters a true value in the iterable. The important part here is that in Python you generally use a generator expression to provide the iterable; for example:  `any(path.startswith(prefix) for prefix in collection_of_prefixes)`. This makes `any()` useful for arbitrary tests. `Collection#contains()` only supports `equals` tests. The Java 8 streaming API  `anyMatch()` test is a good equivalent.

Comment: @MartijnPieters agreed.

Answer (score 11):

In Java 7 and earlier, there is nothing in the standard libraries for doing that.

In Java 8, you should be able to use `Stream.allMatch(...)` or `Stream.anyMatch(...)` for this kind of thing, though I'm not sure that this would be justifiable from a performance perspective.  (For a start, you would need to use `Boolean` instead of `boolean` ...)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Let's see when Java8 hits dalvik.

Answer (score 10):

An example for Java 8 streaming API would be:

```
Boolean[] items = ...;
List<Boolean> itemsList = Arrays.asList(items);
if (itemsList.stream().allMatch(e -> e)) {
    // all
}
if (itemsList.stream().anyMatch(e -> e)) {
    // any
}
```

A solution with the third party library `hamcrest`:

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.everyItem;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasItem;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;

if (everyItem(is(true)).matches(itemsList)) {
    // all
}
if (hasItem(is(true)).matches(itemsList)) { // here is() can be omitted
    // any
}
```